# Using ClientBundle image resources with [SKIN]

Tags: css, gwt, smartgwt

I'm writing a webmail-application by using smartgwt.
I use [SKIN] in smartgwt to select a theme

ex :

```
Img askImg = new Img("[SKIN]Dialog/ask.png", 32, 32);
```

Now, I want to implement the CSS Sprite function.
So, it seems like I have to implement ClientBundle
like

```
public interface MyResources extends ClientBundle {
  public static final MyResources INSTANCE =  GWT.create(MyResources.class);
  /*
  @Source("my.css")
  public CssResource css();*/

  @Source("icons/download-png.png")
  ImageResource logo();


  @Source("[SKIN]Dialog/ask.png")
  ImageResource ask();
}
```

So, the question is
How can I fill the path if I don't know which theme the user use?

Comment: First You have missed / after [SKIN]. It should be `Img askImg = new Img("[SKIN]/Dialog/ask.png", 32, 32);`

Comment: GWT `ClientBundle` and SmartGWT skins looks at different locations for images resources.

Comment: Yes, it's different. How can i decide the skins' location if I don't have the value of skins..

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any solution but you can create a separate class just like Client Bundle and where you can read [SKIN] property directly. Should I code it for you?

Comment: Yeah.. I don't have any idea to read [SKIN]. It would be very helpful if you can share some code.